# Отловить KeyboardInterrput, выполнить функцию и закрыть программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, архитектура

Работаю с множеством данных, данные обрабатывает множество классов. Пытаюсь сделать сохранение текущих обработанных данных после того, как были нажаты `Ctrl+C`, но не хочется постоянно писать одно и то же.

Как возможно максимально сократить строки кода?

```
try:
    working()
except KeyboardInterrput:
    dumpfile(storage_link)
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
def decorator(exc_type=KeyboardInterrput):
    def dec(func):
        def temp(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc_type as e:
                #передаем в dumpfile функцию и её вхожние параметры в случае если произошло исключение
                dumpfile(func, args, kwargs)
                #простого перепорождения должно быть достаточно
                raise e
         return temp
     return dec
```

Использование:

```
 @decorator()
 def working():
     while True:
         pass

 working()
```

Comment: Как-то сложно. Код не читаем для меня. Чуть подробнее можете объяснить?

Comment: decorator это функция которая возврашяет декоратор dec. dec создает функцию temp которая вызывает func и в случае неудачи вызывает dumpfile. Вообще говоря это елементарный код, я незнаю как у вас получилоcь написать "множество классов" и не понять это...)

Comment: С декораторами не работал

Comment: @SomeUser: почему вы думаете, что это сокращает количество строк кода? Код с `except KeyboardInterrupt` пишется ровно в одном месте программы (вы же выходите из программы: `sys.exit()`). Код для одного декоратора уже больше исходного примера в вопросе. В разных программах, вы хотите вероятно слегка разные вещи делать на KeyboardInterrupt -- что вы пытаетесь достичь упрятыванием подобного кода в декоратор?

Answer (score 0):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def dumpfile(storage_link, err=(IndexError, KeyboardInterrput)):
    try: yield
    except err:
        print('dump', storage_link)

def working(storage_link):
    raise KeyboardInterrput
    print(storage_link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    storage_link = 'link'
    with dumpfile(storage_link):
        working(storage_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Более одного раза `KeyboardInterrupt` писать обычно не требуется (иначе реорганизуйте код, чтобы только один раз из главного потока на самом верхнем уровне ловилось исключение или в signal handler для `SIGINT`, если вы переопределили его).

Если вы думаете, что вам нужно чаще `except KeyboardInterrupt` писать, то попробуйте регистрировать `atexit` handler вместо этого для кода, который следует один раз выполнить при нормальном завершении.

Если вы хотите знать как можно код сократить, который cleanup процедуры вызывает в присутствии исключений вообще, то существует множество подходов: try/finally, with-конструкция (`contextlib.ExitStack` для гибкости, если существующих context manager не хватает), декораторы, создание специальных объектов, которые поведение скрывают, итд (практически всё что вы в обычном Питон коде можете использовать, можно применить и для сокращения кода, который исключения обрабатывает в общем случае).